# There any way to open *UberEats* app in a specific restaurant page using URL Schemes or anything else?

Tags: ios, url-scheme, uber-api

There any way to open *UberEats* app in a specific restaurant page using URL Schemes, Deep link, SDK or anything else?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Uber Eats? They are most likely to give you the bedt answer.

Comment: There is not an UberEATS published deeplink scheme currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that and works with current version. Url schema:

`ubereats://`

on the current app you can share a store item and the deeplink is:

`ubereats://store/browse?client_id=eats&storeUUID={STORE_UUID}&itemUUID={ITEM_UUID}`

or simply open the store:

`ubereats://store/browse?client_id=eats&storeUUID={STORE_UUID}`

or apply a promo code:

`ubereats://promo/apply?client_id=eats&promoCode={PROMO_CODE}`

I hope to help

Comment: @MXNMike when your share a store item you can capture the storeUUID and itemUUID

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

`ubereats://promo/apply?client_id=${uberEatsClientKey}&promoCode=${PromoCode}`

It's the same as Uber. You can check the documentation of Uber.